# Is vector::end() guaranteed to be larger than the storage address of any object in the vector?

Tags: c++, vector

The default iterator loop that you find on the Internet looks like this:

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it=myVector.begin(); it!=myVector.end(); it++)
```

Now I want to try some more fancy stuff with iterators. I was thinking about run through e.g. every third element of a vector (`it + 3` as the incrementor), but I fear that this behaviour explodes if I use a different compiler or a different data set as `it + 3` might not be not equal to `vector::end()`, but at the same time not point to something valid as well.

So I wanted to know if it is always true that if

```
it >= myVector.end()
```

then it is not pointing to an element in my vector? Can I use `<` instead of `!=` and be safe that I won't run into compiler-implementation-specific problems?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Wether or not is compiler specific, I think it's not a good idea. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I was thinking about e.g. run through every third element of a vector (it + 3), but I fear that this behaviour explodes if I use a different compiler as (it + 3) might not be end(), but not a valid entry as well.

Comment: `>=` is well-defined for random access iterators, which is what vectors provide. But 1) it adds nothing, and 2) it can't be used with containers with other iterator types (e.g., lists, sets, or maps).

Comment: There are ways it could break even if iterators happen to be simple pointers - e.g. if on your system the vector is placed near the end of a memory segment, a pointer past `end` might wrap back to address 0 in that segment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only iterators that are defined on a vector are iterators pointing to one of its element *and* the end iterator. Any iterator "greater than" end is undefined anyway. Thus, although your comparison might work, it does not add **any** value as the added `>` only makes a difference when comparing with an **undefined iterator**. As using an undefined iterator implies undefined behaviour, you never ever want to have such an iterator anyway. In addition, this also answers your question: Comparing with an undefined iterator is of course also undefined and therefore not guaranteed to yield a meaningful result.

If you want to check, whether an element is in this vector or in another, then `>=` won't help you, too, as comparing these iterators is undefined and will usually boil down to a pointer comparison, so the result depends on which vector has a lower address.

So all in all, using `>=` here simply makes no sense and should therefore be avoided.

As your comment states, you want to iterate through every `n`-th element of a vector. There a various ways to do this in a defined manner, e.g.:

```
(it - vec.begin()) + n < vec.size()
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, I won't do that then. I probably have a too physical & ordered understanding of what "past-the-end element in the vector container" means currently.

Comment: @Blutkoete: Check my last paragraph as an example how you can jump through your vector without undefined behaviour.

Comment: TBH the easier solution is `for (size_t i = 0; i <= vec.size(); i+= 3)`. Certainly a lot easier to read.

Comment: For striding, you can also do `it += std::min( stride, v.end() - it )`.

Answer (score 1):

Why `>=`, instead of `==`?  The end iterator is guaranteed to compare greater than any valid iterator it is not equal to.

Comment: I assume because he wants the `it+=3` loop to also work on vectors with 10 elements, picking `[0], [3], [6], [9]` but not the non-existant `[12]`.